# Carte de séjour as private tutor

Tags: france, resident-permit, south-african-citizens

I want to move to Paris, France, with my two home-schooled kids. I have a BSc and TEFL degree. I want to be a private tutor. I am South African and my main source of income is investments. Is it possible for me to apply for a carte de séjour?

Comment: Does the private tutoring you mention mean only for your childs or do you expect to tutor other childs as a payed work ?

Comment: Notice that home-schooling your own kids in France requires some administrative setup https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F23429

Comment: I want to tutor English to children other than my own. My children are homeschooled online.

Comment: Private tutoring